# Cannot get gmaps geocoding data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have a hidden field inside a form:

```
<form> 
     <input id="distance" name="km" type="hidden">
</form>
```

And I just want to populate this field with the distance between 2 addresses, chosen by the user. Then I simply submit it with the form and do the server stuff with it. Here I call the `calculateDistance` func:

```
$('#my_form_id').on("submit", function (e) {
    calculateDistance();
    // other stuff
    return true;
});
```

This is how I'm trying to get the distance:

```
function calculateDistance() {
    var startPoint = $('#main_from_route_input').val();
    var endPoint = $('#main_to_route_input').val();
    var geocoderStart = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var geocoderEnd = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var coordsStart, coordsEnd;

geocoderStart.geocode({'address': startPoint}, function (response, status) {
    if(status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        alert('Geocode of first address failed: ' + status);
    }
    coordsStart = response[0].geometry.location;

    geocoderEnd.geocode({'address': endPoint}, function (response, status) {
        if(status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            alert('Geocode of second address failed: ' + status);
        }
        coordsEnd = response[0].geometry.location;
        var distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coordsStart, coordsEnd) / 1000).toFixed(2);
        $('#distance').val(distance);
    });
});
}
```

I came up with the upper solution. But I don't even get into the callback functions. When I debug and get to the callback, it is just skipped. The code seems to be correct (the same as in other answers). Where is the problem?

I receive the addresses values as `'Copenhagen, Denmark'` and `'Berlin, Germany'`, for example. I tried making it as in google code snipet suggestions, as follows: `'Copenhagen,+Denmark'` (empty space is replaced with a `+`), but doesn't work still.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript array push it (Salt n Pepa style)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145359/javascript-array-push-it-salt-n-pepa-style)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Geocoding Multiple Locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320267/google-maps-api-geocoding-multiple-locations)

Comment: @geocodezip, I updated my question. Check it out, please.

Comment: You can't  return anything from an asynchronous callback function. You need to **use** the data in the callback function when/where it is available.  What do you want to _use_ the distance for?

Comment: I need to calculate the distance between 2 addresses (provided by the client) so that I can save it in the database.

Comment: Please post the code where you are attempting to save it in the database.  A [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are having would be best.

Comment: Updated. There's no point showing the saving and server-related code, cuz the problem is not there...

Comment: [Your code as posted works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5y11bfvh/), [even with the addresses you provide (updated fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5y11bfvh/1/)

Comment: Perhaps you are submitting the form before the geocoded results have come back?

Comment: I updated the question, so you can see how I handle the submitting of the form. As I said - when I try to debug, I don't even get inside the callback function's body, and at the end `coordsStart` and `coordsEnd` remain `undefined`. I am already using the maps API to draw route on the map and it works perfectly fine, so that's why I am wondering what's the problem with this one...

Comment: You are submitting the form before the geocoder results have come back (as I guessed).  Don't return true from your onsubmit function.  Submit the form after **both** the callback functions have run and you have computed your distance.

Comment: Okay, yes, I fired the `calculateDistance()` function in another place (before I even get to the step of submitting the form) and it was calculated. Now I understand what was the problem. But the result of distance is not calculated correctly... I checked the same route in google maps and there was almost about 95 km difference.

Comment: `computeDistanceBetween` calculates the straight line, as the crow flies distance.  If you want the driving distance, you will have to use the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) or the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

Comment: I see. Okay, thanks a lot! You can write an answer, so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

1. you can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function, you need to use the data inside the callback function.
2. you are submitting the form before the geocoded results have come back (return false in the onsubmit function, then submit the form once all the callback processing has completed.
3. You are calculating the straight line distance (`computeDistanceBetween`) and comparing that to the driving distance.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5y11bfvh/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  calculateDistance();
}

function calculateDistance() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var path = [];
  var startPoint = $('#main_from_route_input').val();
  var endPoint = $('#main_to_route_input').val();
  var geocoderStart = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var geocoderEnd = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var coordsStart, coordsEnd;

  geocoderStart.geocode({
    'address': startPoint
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert('Geocode of first address failed: ' + status);
    }
    coordsStart = response[0].geometry.location;
    bounds.extend(coordsStart);
    var startMark = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coordsStart,
      map: map,
      title: "start"
    });
    path.push(coordsStart);
    geocoderEnd.geocode({
      'address': endPoint
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert('Geocode of second address failed: ' + status);
      }
      coordsEnd = response[0].geometry.location;
      bounds.extend(coordsEnd);
      var endMark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordsEnd,
        map: map,
        title: "end"
      });
      path.push(coordsEnd);
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        map: map
      });
      var distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coordsStart, coordsEnd) / 1000).toFixed(2);
      $('#distance').val(distance);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<form>
  <input id="distance" name="km">
  <input id="main_from_route_input" value="Copenhagen, Denmark" />
  <input id="main_to_route_input" value="Berlin, Germany" />
</form>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```